# Resolve symbol in macro

Tags: clojure

I am stuck on a seemingly basic thing. I have a namespace where I have some definitions:

```
(ns my-namespace)

(def my-definition "HELLO")
(def my-definition2 "HI")
```

Now, I want to use the value of the vars in `my-namespace` in a macro, but I want to retrieve the symbols dynamically. E.g.,

```
(defmacro my-macro [n]
  (-> "my-namespace/my-definition" symbol resolve var-get))
```

Retrieving a symbol in such a manner works in a function (as long as the namespace is loaded), but not in a macro.

In a macro, the symbol cannot be resolved. I've tried quoting and unquoting but it still does not work.

Is it possible in a macro to use the value of a symbol created like that? If so, how?

Comment: `my-namespace` needs to be loaded before `my-macro` is expanded. Is this so?

Comment: Adding `(require [my-namespace :refer :all])` to the macro namespace declaration solved the problem. If you post an answer you can score some points @OlegTheCat, if you're interested in that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbol cannot be resolved, because the namespace where it is defined is not loaded. You can load namespace by

```
(require 'my-namespace)
```

or in namespace declaration:

```
(ns macro-expansion-ns
  (:require [my-namespace]))
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this one:

```
(defmacro my-macro
  [str]
  (-> str symbol resolve deref))
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it doesn't work without requiring the namespace.